# Find Recurring Transaction for invoice

Tags: t-sql, sapb1

For several user defined fields, I would like to be able to find out which recurring transaction template (if any) triggered an Invoice.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a fool-proof link between the two of them.

This is using SAP Business ONE PL 9 and MS SQL Server 2016.

So far, I am getting good results most of the time using the code below.

```
SELECT *  
FROM        ORCP    T0
INNER JOIN  ODRF    T1 ON T0.DraftEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T0.DraftEntry = 
                     (
                       SELECT DocEntry
                       FROM ODRF
                       WHERE CardCode = '12345' 
                       AND DocTotal = '1000' 
                       AND ObjType = '13' 
                       AND CANCELED = 'N'
                     )
```

Unfortunately, this is very dependent on well-crafted draft documents.

Comment: Thanks for your script, however, could you perhaps provide us with sample data and your expected results?

Comment: The expected result would be a *single* row of data from ORCP. As it stands right now, there is the possibility of several rows due to re-use of draft documents for recurring transaction templates. I am not sure how to provide meaningful sample data for a complex database like this.

Comment: the subquery looks redundant, why not just put everything in the where out and get rid of the subquery?

Comment: I understand that it is a complex database, all the more reason to provide us with sample data. Help us help you...